# Getting complete URL of User's Google Profile Picture

Tags: android, user-profile, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I use **Google** sign-in in an **Android app** and save a link to their **profile picture URL** in the **database**.

In the past, I would get the complete URL, starting with this one of these, for example:

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/{random stuff}/photo.jpg
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/{random stuff}/photo.jpg
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/{random stuff}/photo.jpg
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/{random stuff}/photo.jpg
```

Ever since Google Play Services updated this (I think in 8.3?) I only get

```
/{random stuff}/photo.jpg
```

This obviously won't link to a picture.

Here is my code:

```
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

    if (acct != null) 
    {
        String profilePicPath = "";
        if (acct.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
            profilePicPath = acct.getPhotoUrl().getPath();
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:  I believe what I am doing wrong is I added `getPath()` after the URL.**

Comment: Yes, remove the getPath() will give you the full url.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was this:

I added `getPath()` here `profilePicPath = acct.getPhotoUrl().getPath();`.  Instead, I removed that, got its string form, and that is all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need Enabling G+ API on google console.

[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_1_enable_the_google_api)

You will need to initialize the GoogleApiClient

[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html)

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   ......
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .build();
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(googleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);



    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(googleApiClient) != null) {
        Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(googleApiClient);
        personNameView.setText(person.getDisplayName());
        if (person.hasImage()) {

            Person.Image image = person.getImage();


            new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                        InputStream in = url.openStream();
                        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    /* TODO log error */
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    personImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }.execute(image.getUrl());
        }
   }
```

[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.Image)

Hope this helps

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't this the old way of doing it?  I don't think they use the `Plus` stuff anymore?  I think this is how I used to do it and it worked fine; and then they changed things a few months or weeks ago.